# How can I access services via subdomain instead of ip + port?

Tags: port, subdomain

I have a little server in my local network that provides several web services. Each service can be accessed by entering the ip of the server followed by the respective port.

Now I always have to remember which service is behind which port and it would be nicer to have specific subdomains forwarded to these ports. For example
ip:1234 -> foo.server.local
ip:4321 -> bar.server.local

How can this be done? I have pihole running on the server and had hoped to get this done using pihole but I was not successful.

Comment: What you are looking for is to set up a Domain Name Server (DNS). https://phoenixnap.com/kb/raspberry-pi-dns-server This guide should help.

Comment: But this only assigns ip addresses to (sub-)domains and not ports or am I mistaken?

Comment: No, you would use a domain to direct to an IP:port combo. Like you could direct 123.12.12.12:8080 to some.thing and 123.12.12.12:8081 to any.address. The domain name is arbitrary and masks the whole IP:port address.

Comment: It worked just as you said. Would you like to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Great to hear! Posted an answer there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to set up a Domain Name Server (DNS). phoenixnap.com/kb/raspberry-pi-dns-server This guide should help.

You use a domain to direct to an `IP:port combo`. Like you could direct `123.12.12.12:8080` to `some.thing` and `123.12.12.12:8081` to `any.address`.
The domain name is arbitrary and masks the whole IP:port address.